# The overall Gibbs free energy in Gluconeogenesis

Tags: thermodynamics, biochemistry

Gluconeogenesis is an exergonic process but I wonder what is the overall Gibbs free energy in step 3 and step 10?

I know there’s about $\pu{2\times ( -31.4 ) kJ/mol}$ for 2 pyruvates convert to 2 phosphoenolpyruvates (PEP). The reverse reaction path would vary in gluconeogenesis, but there’s no information on the web on this reverse energy.

Gluconeogenesis step 10:

$\ce{2 Pyruvate + 4 ATP + 2 GTP ->[Acetyl CoA、Biotin Pyruvate carboxylase][Mg^{2+}] 2PEP + 4ADP + 2GDP + 6Pi}$

Step 3:

$\ce{\mathrm{F1,6BP} + H2O ->[Fructo-1,6-bisphosphatase] \mathrm{F6P} + Pi}$

Comment: Would be nice if you elaborated what those steps are.

Comment: What is the meaning of the commas (,), after CoA and between carboxylase and Mg2+ ? Why do you write arrows from time to time with and sometimes without the final arrow (>) ?

Comment: Please see https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/faq-how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-on-chemistry-stack-exchange on how to format equations and chemical expressions.

Comment: I tried to improve your post with some edits but as Maurice points out, there are some odd formatting features and nonstandard chemical notation. Please edit this for clarity, those features might be the result of copy-pasting.

Comment: Also, the question in the title and body don't match. Please edit that.